# Rewriting a power series as a geometric series?

Tags: power-series

For this series, find the radius of convergence and write it as a geometric series and give a formula if $x>3$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(x-3)^n$$

Now finding the radius of convergence wasn't too difficult and I'll save you guys the trouble of doing it because the interval of convergence is $  -1 = 3 - 4< x < 4 + 3 = 7$ and so the radius of convergence is 2

The second part confuses me because I don't understand (if it is even possible) to convert a power series to a geometric series.

Comment: You are confusing the radius of curvature with the radius of convergence, and you got the wrong answer.

Comment: What if we set $\dfrac{x-3} 2 $ as $r$, and take $1/2$ out?

Comment: Oh shoot, wrong term. I have no idea why i did that Gerry.

Comment: You still have the wrong answer for the radius of convergence.

Comment: Yes, I made a careless mistake. Thank you for catching that Gerry again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular function, shouldn't one note that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}(x-3)^n = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}(x-3)^n = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\left(\frac{x-3}{2}\right)^{n}$$
which **is** a geometric series!

Comment: You haven't left OP much to do, have you?

Comment: As for the radius of convergence, we need
$$
\biggl| \dfrac{x - 3}{2} \biggr| < 1. 
$$

Comment: @Eugene, I basically also got what Alex has, but why are you assuming $\biggl| \dfrac{x - 3}{2} \biggr| < 1$ instead of $|x - 3| < 2$? I realize you can't use $1/(1 - x)$ if I don't assume that the ratio is less than 1. But when x > 3, doesn't the sum diverge?

Comment: @jak What you wrote is the same thing as what I wrote just so you know.

Comment: Oh It's because you substituted $r = \biggl| \dfrac{x - 3}{2} \biggr| < 1$. Okay gotcha

Comment: @jak The thing is, here we don't care if $a$ is complex (it is $2$) but if it was complex $|z|$ is not necessarily $= z$. You would've gotten a different result if it was $\frac{x-2}{-2}$, maybe.

Comment: @jak:  the leading factor doesn't contribute to the radius of convergence, only to the value it converges to.  When you write $\left| \frac {x-3}2 \right | \lt 1$ this is the same as $|x-3| \lt 2$ so the radius of convergence is 2, centered at $x=3$

Comment: @jak:  but the leading $\frac 12$ is not part of the ratio.  The ratio between successive terms is just $\left| \frac {x-3}2 \right|$ which is what needs to be $\lt 1$.  The $\frac 12$ divides out in the ratio.

Comment: @everyoen sorry, you are right R = 2. I got 4 because I forget to carry a (1/2) when I DIVIDE.

Comment: The sum then simplifies to $\frac{1}{5-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not *always* possible to convert a power series to a geometric series, but in this case it can be done. A geometric series is $a+ar+ar^2+\dots$, all you have to do is a little pattern matching to figure out what $a$ and $r$ have to be in your example.